# Looking for assistance with script hanging on a server and not completing

Tags: powershell, scripting

So, as long as the below script runs without hitting a dead or frozen server.. it does exactly what I want it too, however... should it hit a server that is dead or frozen, it just hangs on that one server and never completes. What I would like to do is after x amount of time, or failure, it moves on so there is no downtime. Please help?!

With the examples and suggestions below, I am still kind of lost on how to implement the -asjob commands. We are trying to keep this script a little more simple. Can someone please guide me? Or, is there a simpler way to just skip the server that isn't responding with the first ping?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$allservers = get-adcomputer -filter * -searchbase "xxxxx -prop Operatingsystem | where-object {$_.DistinguishedName -NotLike '*OU=NEC*' -and $_.DistinguishedName -Notlike '*OU=GPO_Testing*'} 

$winservers = ($allservers | where {$_.OperatingSystem -like "Windows Server*"}).name
$notwinservers = $allservers | where {$_.OperatingSystem -notlike "Windows Server*"}

$scriptblock = {
   
    # Set the server name
       $serverName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

    # Get the up/down status of the server
       $pingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
       $status = if ($pingResult.StatusCode -eq 0) {
          'Up'
       }
      else {
        'Down'
      }
    
    # Get the server build date
       $buildDate = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).InstallDate

    # Certificate name information
       $certname = get-childitem -path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ |
        Select friendlyname 

    # Get the server certificate validity
    [array] $certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My |
        Where-Object { -Not $_.PSIsContainer } |
        Sort-Object -Property NotBefore        

    # Last reboot
       $reboot = get-ciminstance -classname win32_operatingsystem | select LastBootUpTime

    # Number of Certs on Machine
       $certcount = (get-childitem -path Cert:\LocalMachine\my).count

    # Check Trellix update
       $TrellixDate = [datetime](Get-ItemProperty 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\McAfee\Engine\AMCoreUpdater\amupdate.dat').LastWriteTime.DateTime

    # Operating system collection
       $os = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).operatingsystem# | Select-Object Caption
    
    # Disk information
    [array] $diskInfo = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter 'DriveType = 3'

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt [System.Math]::Max($cert.Count, $diskInfo.Count); $i++) {
        $disk = $diskInfo[$i]
        $freeSpace = $diskSize = $percent = $label = $null

        $cert = $certs[$i]

        if ($disk) {
            $label = $disk.DeviceID
            $freeSpace = $disk.FreeSpace / 1GB
            $diskSize = $disk.Size / 1GB
            $percent = '{0:P0}' -f ($freeSpace / $diskSize)
          }

        $validTo = $validFrom = $null
        if ($cert) {
            $validTo = $cert.NotAfter
            $validFrom = $cert.NotBefore
        }

    # SQL Version
       if (test-path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
         $sql = (get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances
          foreach ($i in $sql) 
           {
          $sqlver = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL').$i
        (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").Version
        }
       }
       else {$sqlver = "n/a"}

    # IIS version, if available
      if (Get-Service -Name W3SVC -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
      $IIS = (Get-ItemProperty -PATH 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\').VERSIONSTRING
               }
       else {$iis = "n/a"}
    
    # Describing the Columns for Output
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            ServerName           = $serverName
            Status               = $status
            OperatingSystem      = $os
            BuildDate            = '{0:u}' -f $buildDate
            LastReboot           = $reboot
            CertName             = $certname
            CertCreated          = $validFrom
            CertExpiration       = $validTo
            CertCount            = $certcount
            TrellixLastUpdate    = $TrellixDate
            SQLVersion           = $sqlver
            IISVersion           = $IIS
            DiskLabel            = $label
            Freespace            = '{0:N2} Gb' -f $freespace
            DiskSize             = '{0:N2} Gb' -f $disksize
            PercentFree          = $percent
         }
    }
}


       
    # Command to run the script on the servers
      Invoke-Command -ComputerName $winservers -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -HideComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue|
      Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId, PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName | 

    # Export-Csv e:\activetasks\server_checks\DailyServerReport_$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation
      Export-Csv e:\activetasks\server_checks\DailyMissionReport_$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation

    #Second portion of the script to append the non windows Servers to the end of the spreadsheet.

    foreach ($nonwin in $notwinservers){

    # Get the up/down status of the server
       $pingResult = Test-Connection -ComputerName $nonwin.name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
       $status = if ($pingResult.StatusCode -eq 0) {
          'Up'
       }
      else {
        'Down'
      }
      

    [PSCustomObject]@{
            ServerName           = $($nonwin.name)
            Status               = $status 
            OperatingSystem      = "Linux or Other"
            BuildDate            = "n/a"
            LastReboot           = "n/a"
            CertName             = "n/a"
            CertCreated          = "n/a"
            CertExpiration       = "n/a"
            CertCount            = "n/a"
            TrellixLastUpdate    = "n/a"
            SQLVersion           = "n/a"
            IISVersion           = "n/a"
            DiskLabel            = "n/a"
            Freespace            = "n/a"
            DiskSize             = "n/a"
            PercentFree          = "n/a"
         }|
          
          Export-Csv e:\activetasks\server_checks\DailyMissionReport_$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation -append
        
      }
```

Comment: Could you narrow this down to an MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example). That would make it easier for someone to provide an answer. In the third line of the code, where does the QUOTATION MARK close?

Comment: I apologize, I included the entire code as to figure out if there is somewhere or something that can be added. I can reduce the scriptblock. I am still slightly new to powershell and am struggling a bit to figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: The easiest option here would probably be to add `-AsJob` to `Invoke-Command`, then you can use `Wait-Job` and/or `Receive-Job` to wait for a max timeout. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_jobs?view=powershell-7.4#how-to-run-as-a-detached-process

Comment: in combination to the previous comment, you can run `-AsJob` with `-ThrottleLimit` to have concurrent connections. This will speed things up this way the timed out session will not interfere with your workflowhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.4